# Run set of commands in parallel with powershell

Tags: powershell, parallel-processing, powershell-5.1

The script below is running and check if each sql file exist in one of the trunk locations (I have 20) with all the combination of the sql name (each $res). this will run for a long time if I have many sql files. basically I want to know if there is a sql file that exists in the trunk location, break the loop and store the trunk name. in order to do it more quick I want to run in parallel (I am using powershell 5.1 and cannot working with PS 7)

```
write-host "Starting to search sqls in all trunk locations"
            foreach ($sql in $sqls) {
            Write-Host "Working on $($sql.name)" -ForegroundColor Yellow
            $results = ConvertTo-DecodedPath $sql.Name
            foreach ($trunk in $TrunkList) {
                Write-Host "Working on $trunk" -ForegroundColor Cyan
               foreach ($res in $results) {
                 
                 $searchedText = ("File Name" + "=" + '"' + $res + '"').Replace("/", "\")
                 write-host "Working on $searchedText"
                 $xmlPathInTfs = $trunk + '/' + "InstallationFiles.xml"
                 $checkFileContentTfsResult = CheckFileExistsTfs $xmlPathInTfs $searchedText
                 if ($checkFileContentTfsResult.SearchedTextFound) {
                    write-host "[$($sql.name)] was found in [$trunk]" -ForegroundColor green
                    break
                 }
              } 
           }
        }
```

Comment: Wow ... that's a lot of code to review. You may change this to a [MRE]. Have you considered using PowerShell version 7.x and its built in [Foreach-Object -Parallel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.3)?

Comment: Don't need to review all...just want to run in parallel for each sql file

Comment: As I explained each file is tested and if all good I print him and if not he stored to a proper list and in the end I print them

Comment: It only make sense to run items in parallel if you are going to get a performance improvement. Windows is a multi-process operating system that is already doing tasks in parallel.  So there is a limit you will achieve to parallel performance improvement.  It depends on the number of core in the micro.  SQL Server has a connection pool that is used for parallel commands and this also limits the max number of queries that will run at one time.  SQL Server also has locks to prevent conflicts when two queries use same resource to prevent conflicts.   The locks also slow down performance.

Comment: @jdweng the query is not performed against any sql server. only against TFS

Comment: Basically: [`$sqls |Foreach-Object -Parallel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object#-parallel) (and replace all the `$sql`variables with the current variable: `$_`) but as suggested in the other comments, you probably leverage more from other [PowerShell scripting performance considerations](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/dev-cross-plat/performance/script-authoring-considerations)

Comment: The TFS can get a lot of requests...I must using PS 5
Any other option?

Comment: "*I must using PS 5*"  Why?  `¯\_(ツ)_/¯` If the assignment requires parallel processing and the tool to accomplish this is a newer PowerShell version, why can't you use it?

Comment: Even if I will use it I don't know how to convert it and this is the reason I asked this

Comment: "*Even if I will use it I don't know how to convert it*", start with creating a [mcve] of the "*Wow ... that's a lot of code to review*" (see first comment). Do not expect anybody to rewrite your code here (see: [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)). Try to avoid to frame this to a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: You can get the threadjob module for powershell 5.1.  `Install-Module ThreadJob`

Comment: @js2010 thank you. can you explain how to use it? how to convert my script

Comment: I tried to add the Start-ThreadJob -ScriptBlock after the foreach ($sql in $sqls) {

the -ScriptBlock is all the foreach ($trunk in $TrunkList) {

Its not working, maybe I need to wait until the job finished

Comment: Something like `$list | foreach-object { $_ | start-threadjob { do-work $input } } | receive-job -wait -auto`